# Did the token fingerprint hash algorithm change?

Tags: native-assets

I have an question about the asset fingerprint.

For example here:
https://pool.pm/333427e94971f530653bb945f34f914252ad570c0b84dfd8c8e8c97b.ExtraHate067
it shows `asset1yjj6l5ude4gf274ya0exk4vymaaj0464yxmnvm`

here it shows the same: https://cardano-tools.io/latest?q=ExtraHate067

but the explorer
https://explorer.cardano.org/en/transaction?id=0d560535733237eaafa4f3c25e648d147dc93a048e3dc66e5199cd86986b5a2c
shows `asset1q7c0qhulpty4tcdp3cwt8eg5edws9c8lqyldlr` did they change the hash algorithm?

Comment: Yes, it's really strange. I managed to find a transaction where fingerprints are equal. Necromancer 003 https://cardano-tools.io/latest?q=f4988f549728dc76b58d7677849443caf6e5385dc67e6c25f6aa901e https://explorer.cardano.org/en/transaction?id=a4b4c4c637bf297af7ece2079bdbf6af8bbbcb6611603ae8a6109a47ea804de7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, good catch. You can see fingerPrint function [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-graphql/blob/11c4eb81f7790d93807cc760c05e4a3552677525/packages/api-cardano-db-hasura/src/DataSyncController.ts#L15). It's located in `cardano-graphql` project.

```
export const assetFingerprint = (asset: Pick<Asset, 'assetName' | 'policyId'>) =>
  new AssetFingerprint(
    Buffer.from(asset.policyId, 'hex'),
    asset.assetName !== '' ? Buffer.from(asset.assetName, 'hex') : undefined)
    .fingerprint()
```

After running this code

```
const fingerPrint = ({ policyId, assetName }) => {
  const af = new AssetFingerprint(
    Buffer.from(policyId, 'hex'),
    Buffer.from(assetName, 'hex'),
  ).fingerprint()

  return af
}

const combinations = [
  {policyId:'333427e94971f530653bb945f34f914252ad570c0b84dfd8c8e8c97b',
   assetName:'457874726148617465303637'},
  {policyId: "",
   assetName:'457874726148617465303637'},
  {policyId: '333427e94971f530653bb945f34f914252ad570c0b84dfd8c8e8c97b',
   assetName: ""},
]

combinations.map(fingerPrint)
```

I got

```
[
  'asset1yjj6l5ude4gf274ya0exk4vymaaj0464yxmnvm',
  'asset1q7c0qhulpty4tcdp3cwt8eg5edws9c8lqyldlr',
  'asset19nqnahcv54krdv8mcc0ne60wlkealw5qaztzvp'
]
```

Which means that `policyId` is missing in the explorer but the fingerprint function is the same.

You can rerun my code in [replit](https://replit.com/@yanisurbis/token-fingerprint#index.js).

I also created an [issue](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-explorer-app/issues/410) for `cardano-explorer-app`.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a bug in `explorer.cardano.org`.

You can use the JS package `@emurgo/cip14-js` to check for yourself.

```
import AssetFingerprint from '@emurgo/cip14-js'

const assetFingerprint = new AssetFingerprint(
    Buffer.from('333427e94971f530653bb945f34f914252ad570c0b84dfd8c8e8c97b', 'hex'),
    Buffer.from('457874726148617465303637', 'hex'),
  )
assetFingerprint.fingerprint()
// returns asset1yjj6l5ude4gf274ya0exk4vymaaj0464yxmnvm
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-graphql/pull/526. Thanks for the investigation.

Edit: Released in [5.0.0](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-graphql/releases/tag/5.0.0), adopted by `cardano-explorer-app` in [1.6.0](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-explorer-app/releases/tag/1.6.0)